# Which is the suitable preposition for a perspective?

Tags: word-choice

Consider several well known phenomena. I would like to describe these phenomena from a different point of view.

Do I allow a different perspective ***on*** these phenomena, ***of*** the phenomena, ***at*** all phenomena in focus, or should I use a different proposition?

Comment: Diffident propositions definitely are best whenever you are uncertain, but if you've got the facts, go for boldness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have a different perspective ***of*** a phenomenon if you are using the "perception" meaning of perspective.

> Members of the audience had different perspectives of the stage, depending on their seat.

If instead you want to use the "opinion" meaning of perspective, then you would have a perspective ***on*** a phenomenon (with the implication that you want to share and argue in support of your perspective).

> Members of the audience had different perspectives on the performance as they left the theatre, depending on their tastes.

You can't have a perspective ***at*** a phenomenon without a fairly strange set of circumstances and taking a bit of poetic license with the language. Such a construction simply sounds wrong, unless the context strongly indicates that having a perspective can somehow have an effect on the phenomenon being focused upon. Such a context might happen in a fantasy novel where mental powers can change the world, but wouldn't be correct in more mundane writing contexts. Even in a fantastical context, it would take a better writer than I to craft such a sentence that didn't sound awkward:

> I forcefully thought my different perspective at the magical wildfire, trying to impose my will on reality and extinguish the flames.